# connection fail to connect mongodb in node application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, towerjs

I have an error while starting up server with node server.js. The error details are here:

```
path.existsSync is now called `fs.existsSync`.
info  - socket.io started
[Thu, 02 Aug 2012 00:58:27 GMT] INFO Tower development server listening on port 3000
[Error: Target script does not exist: node_modules/design.io/bin/design.io]

/Users/Drew/test/desert-level-pets/node_modules/tower/lib/tower/server/store/mongodb/database.js:39
            throw error;
                ^
Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/Users/Drew/test/desert-level-pets/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:473:73)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
    at connection.on._self._poolState (/Users/Drew/test/desert-level-pets/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:92:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
    at Socket.errorHandler (/Users/Drew/test/desert-level-pets/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:387:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
    at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:329:14)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9
```

Can anyone can help me to solve it?
Thanks,

Comment: `Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]` suggests that you don't have a [MongoDB server](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) running on that IP address and port.  You can check the server connection with the `mongo` shell before trying to connect with NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make sure you have an instance of mongodb up and running. Also, did you run "npm install" in the directory your attempting to run "tower server" in to install design.io and all the other packages tower needs? Looks like that's part of the problem.